# ICACLS Failed Processing Files on Sub folders

Tags: batch-file, icacls

Currently I am working on a batch file to grant or deny permission to all of the users on execution of the batch file.

The problem I am facing is that the command which I am working on provides an output of **"Failed Processing 1 files**

Here is the piece of code I am working on

```
set locationfolder=C:\Users\Troy\Desktop\Log Folder
icacls "%locationfolder%" /deny Everyone:F /T
```

So here is the output I get,

```
processed file: C:\Users\Users\Troy\Desktop\Log Folder
C:\Users\Users\Troy\Desktop\Log Folder\*: Access is denied
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 1 files
```

Now the subfolders and subfiles of the folder is as follows

**Log Folder**

- Log Folder 1
- Confidential.txt

Now Log Folder 1 Contains following subfolder

**Log Folder 1**

- Log Folder 2

**Log Folder 2** contains the following sub folder

- Log Folder 3

And finally **Log Folder 3** contains the following subfolder and subfiles

- userdetails.txt

Now I would like to grant or deny permissions to all users based on the execution of batch file to that specific path mentioned above along with all of its subfiles and subfolders. However only the base folder ie. C:\Users\Troy\Desktop\Log Folder retains the deny permission, whereas all of the subfolders can be easily accessed, if approached directly.

For eg if I enter in the location bar of the Windows File Explorer as 
C:\Users\Users\Troy\Desktop\Log Folder, it gives me `Access is Denied` Error. which is what I expect.
However if I input C:\Users\Users\Troy\Desktop\Log Folder\Log Folder 1\Log Folder 2, it permits me to browse the contents of the subfolder.

From what I can deduce from the output of the above code ie.

```
C:\Users\Users\Troy\Desktop\Log Folder\*: Access is denied
```

This probably means that Access is denied for * ie. for all subfolders and sub files a result of which they do not deny permissions.

I have also tried this code but it leads to the same result

```
icacls "%locationfolder%" /deny "Everyone":(OI)(CI)F /T
```

I have also tried on other directories and also running CMD in Administrator mode, but all in vain.

Also to let you know if I use the same code with /grant switch it works as intended. ie,

```
icacls "%locationfolder%" /grant Everyone:F /T
```

Returns the following output.

```
Successfully processed 7 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Hence whatever the problem is appears to be with /deny switch.

Please help.

Comment: In the first case, you're denying everyone access to the directory, so obviously `/T` fails because it's not allowed to list the directory. You should be able to do this with just inheritance (e.g. `icacls "%locationfolder%" /deny Everyone:(OI)(CI)F`), assuming the security of all subdirectories and files has inheritance enabled.

Comment: @eryksun How do I ensure that inheritance is enabled in sub-directories ?
Sorry, if I am asking a stupid question, I am a beginner.
Also I tried using two things
First I tried using the  command as you mentioned   
`icacls "%locationfolder%" /deny Everyone:(OI)(CI)F`
What this does is it only works on the base folder and not on sub directories as I previously mentioned.  
Secondly I tried using /T switch on the above command, it gives the same error of Failed to process 1 File.
Please help.

Comment: The easiest option is to `/reset /T` the tree, but only if that's reasonable -- i.e. don't reset the security if you have custom security settings on individual files and directories that will be lost.

Comment: @eryksun That fixed it. I cannot thank you enough. Hope you have a nice day.